# Invoking a PowerShell script from Python

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to start a PowerShell script from python like this:

```
psxmlgen = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',
                             './buildxml.ps1',
                             arg1, arg2, arg3], cwd=os.getcwd())
result = psxmlgen.wait()
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

> File
>   C:\Users\sztomi\workspace\myproject\buildxml.ps1
>   cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this
>   system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.

DESPITE the fact that I did enable running scripts in Powershell a long time ago by typing `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestriced` in an administrator-ran PS terminal (and did again, just to make sure). The powershell executable is the same that the shortcut in start menu points to. `Get-ExecutionPolicy` correctly reports `Unrestricted` no matter if I ran PowerShell as admin or not.

How can I execute a PS script correctly from Python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestriced` is on a per user basis, and a per bitness basis (32-bit is different than 64-bit).

Second, you can override the execution policy from the command line.

```
psxmlgen = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',
                             '-ExecutionPolicy',
                             'Unrestricted',
                             './buildxml.ps1',
                             arg1, arg2, arg3], cwd=os.getcwd())
result = psxmlgen.wait()
```

Apparently you can access the 64-bit PowerShell from 32-bit PowerShell with this path (thanks to @eryksun in comments):

```
powershell64 = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 
    'SysNative' if platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' else 'System32',
    'WindowsPowerShell', 'v1.0', 'powershell.exe')
```

Comment: Wow that's great, thank you! Actually, I just figured out that the problem was due to the infamous filesystem-redirection of Windows 7 x64. (I had Unrestricted policy in the x64 version, but not in the x86, and python was not redirect to it).

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to call an executable like that with subprocess, but just to clarify, is the './buildxml.ps1' the actual command that is being called?

Comment: @someone-or-other buildxml.ps1 is a powershell script file and the executable (if that is what you mean by command) is `'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'`. All the items in the list that follow are parameters that are passed to this executable.

Comment: so if you wanted to call "ls" (which is an example, that could be done with "dir") you would put that in one of the arg variables?

Comment: Use the virtual "SysNative" directory to run a native 64-bit system executable from a 32-bit WOW64 program. Also, don't hard code the system root directory "C:\Windows"; that's not always where Windows is installed. I would use `powershell64 = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'SysNative' if platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' else 'System32', 'WindowsPowerShell', 'v1.0', 'powershell.exe')`.

Comment: @eryksun  Thank you for that, I have added it to the answer for more visibility with credit.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who wanted to know how to display the values of arg1, arg2 and arg3 after it was passed to powershell, all you need to do is:

```
Write-Host $args[0]
Write-Host $args[1]
Write-Host $args[2]
```