# How do I copy files from windows system to any other remote server from python script?

Tags: python, windows

I don't want to use external modules like paramiko or fabric. Is there any python built in module through which we can transfer files from windows. I know for linux scp command is there like this is there any command for windows ?

Comment: You can always simply use sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) is stable, simple and supports Linux, OS X and Windows.

You can install via pip:

```
pip install paramiko
```

Simple Demo:

```
import base64
import paramiko
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.b64decode(b'AAA...'))
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.get_host_keys().add('ssh.example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)
client.connect('ssh.example.com', username='strongbad', password='thecheat')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
client.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to `scp` is the `Copy-Item` cmdlet that's available in Powershell, You could execute powershell and run a `Copy-Item` command to copy a file from your local windows system to another directory or a remote server directory.

You need to first set the PowerShell for unrestricted access by doing `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestriced` after which you can use the `subprocess` module of python to make a call to execute the required script.

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901856/invoking-a-powershell-script-from-python) is of help to you.

Comment: Are you referring to PowerShell 5 remoting and the `FromSession` and `ToSession` options, as described in the latest docs for the [`Copy-Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) cmdlet? Or were you just proposing the use of a UNC target path? That would work just as well with cmd's `copy`, `xcopy.exe`  or `robocopy.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

## Server

`python -m http.server`

this will create a http server on port 8000

## client

`python -c "import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve('http://x.x.x.x:8000/filename', 'filename')"`

where x.x.x.x is your server ip, filename is what you want to download